# Google Cloud Platform & APIs: Payment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, payment

Google is trying to charge $178 from my account, I don't even know what google console for, I don't even have a business, anyway can someone tell me how to cancel or deactivate google platform, because I don't need it. please

Answer (score 0):

That is going to happen when you have test for something on Cloud console and forget to close that service or account.

In this case you can drop a massage to google cloud from your account.

You can submit a unknown charges billing form.

```
https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_unknown_charges
```

For more details you can explore this page.

```
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues
```